# Unable to open files in VS Code via terminal over SSH

Tags: vscode-remote

I have a windows10 machine using Remote-SSH to interface with repo on an Ubuntu18.04 system.

Until about a month ago I was able to open files using VS Code's integrated terminal.
Now entering `code ./myFile.txt` returns immediately. No error, no file opened.

If a non existent file is opened `code ./myNonExistentFile.txt` the same thing happens.

Running `code ./myFile.txt` into an entirely local setup (no Remote-SSH) works; the file opens in VS Code.
Remote-SSH is otherwise working.

Has anybody else noticed this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

It's expected. You probably don't have vs-code on a remote machine, nor have forwarded the X-server thus nothing will happen when you run this.

I suggest mounting the remote file system to local machine and run `code .` locally: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sshfs-to-mount-remote-file-systems-over-ssh

Comment: I have restarted the client side (Win10) VS-Code and restarted the VS-Code server.  No joy. 
The sshfs looks like an interesting alternative approach. 
However the Remote-SSH plugin used to work seamlessly and it still works well, apart from this issue. I'd love to get back to that place.

Answer (score 0):

**@Max Lobur** may be right. If not, you still feel free to restart the VS Code.

Comment: I agree - always try this first :D

Answer (score 0):

As a last resort, try deleting your server's .vscode-server folder, which is located at your home folder, as detailed in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/1443